# Slow defaults access for key ClientState on dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler

Tags: ios, url

I am getting this warning when executing an url by the method in the title on my iPhone 4 with iOS 7 and the operation fails returning "not valid url", while when connecting to the url in the browser I have no problems at all, nor I have them when I execute the app in the simulator.
What might it be? And in particular would it just affect my device, iOS 7 or everyone? I just submitted the update with this operation and I would like to know if it works or not before the release of it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to my using in the url of character '|' as a separator for the date instead of the blank when submitting it as a get parameter; when I substituted it with ';' everything worked fine.